# Login menu which I added in main menu still displaying even after logged-in

Tags: 7, routes, users

I have used login (`user/login`) as menu item in the main menu. While I am logged out, it displays login menu link properly.

When I am logged in, still displays me `login` as a menu item. But I dont want to be displayed or instead  'logout' over their.

I tried adding logout(`user/logout`) as seperate menu, but still no luck it shows as a separate menu item. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two have two menu items, login and logout.

For the login link the path is: user/login
and for logout the path is: user/logout

Make sure you don't enter a absolute URL to the links, just user/login and user/logout.

I have just tested this by adding two menu items to the primary menu.

Comment: Thanks and its weird. Same set of things i actually tried, but didn't work.One more time i tried it actually works. Thanks for your time any way :)

Comment: Simple and nice method. Works perfectly.